# Different RAM stics on the same Motherboard?

Tags: memory, motherboard, upgrade

I was doing some research about installing RAM on the motherboard. I have [Acer Predator G3620](https://www.manualslib.com/products/Acer-Predator-G3620-2593990.html) motherboard, and I have a 2x [4GB UNB PC3-10600 CL9 DDR3](https://www.ebay.com/itm/192145067866) on it.

Now, I had this older computer that I want to use RAM sticks and combine with this Predator one because I had two more slots left on the motherboard. The following RAM sticks are:

- [DDR3 UDIMM - 240-pin Desktop Ram - Non-ECC - (99) (2GB (1x2GB), DDR3-1333MHz (PC3 10666)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002YCF6QU)
- DDR3 4GB, 1333MHz, DIMM, PC10600 CL9, brand RC Memory

I haven't put them and tested it because I am afraid that something will happen.

I also ask because I have read somewhere that the order of inserting RAM sticks matters. I have different brands, same speed, all DDR3, but one of them is 2GB while others are 4.

Can someone help me regarding this? Thanks

Comment: its a pretty ugly configuration, but as long as the voltage matches it will probably work, just not terribly fast. because your sticks don't match (in size across both channels), you will be using single-channel memory access, which will run at 667MHz instead of 1333. it may be worth it if you are running too low on RAM, but it won't be just like it was but with more RAM.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.